# Index out of bounds error when using Rcpp function with mapply

Tags: r, rcpp

I get `"Error: index out of bounds"` when I am using `mapply` with a Rcpp function:

R:

```r
mapply(fun, x = totPrimas, y = factorProjec, w = totCurvadf)
```

`x`, `y` and `z` are data frames with the same dimensions.

Rcpp:

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector fun(const NumericVector x, const NumericVector y, const NumericVector w ) {
  NumericVector z(x.size()); 
  z(0) = x(0) * y(0);
  NumericVector c(x.size()); 
  c(0) = x(0) * w(0);
  for(int i = 1; i < x.size(); i++) {
    c(i) = (c(i-1) + x(i)) * w(i); 
    z(i) = c(i) * y(i);
  }
  return z;
}
```

Is something wrong in the code? Thanks alot.

Comment: I don't understand "x, y and z are data frames with the same dimensions." How does that relate to your code?

Comment: I can't see an index going out of bounds in there C++ code. So, the problem is probably what you are passing to `fun` via `mapply`. Hence my request for clarification.

Comment: Thanks, I checked the input and you are right. "w" is a matrix, I converted it to data.frame and works well. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've noted, the problem was that `totCurvadf` was a matrix. The reason this was an issue is that `aMatrix[1]` will return a vector of length 1, whereas `aDataFrame[1]` will return the first column of the data.frame as a vector of length equal to `nrow(aDataFrame)`.

If you did want to do this with matrices (or a mixture of data frames and matrices, you could do:

```
lapply(1:nrow(totPrimas), function(i) fun(x = totPrimas[, i], y = factorProjec[, i], w = totCurvadf[, i]))
```